# Postfix: Untrusted TLS connection established - How to solve this error?

Tags: debian, postfix

I use `Postfix` in combination with Lets Encrypt to transmit TLS encrypted e-mails.

The following parameters in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` are relevant:

```
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.bar/privkey.pem
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.bar/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.bar/fullchain.pem
```

I can send e-mails without problems, but I get the warning message that Postfix cannot verify the certificate of the receiving site:

```
postfix/smtp[10736]: Untrusted TLS connection established to example.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
```

I suspect this is because Postfix is not able to access its certificate store with this parameter:

```
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.bar/fullchain.pem
```

A change to `smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs` will break my entire TLS-Configuration.

What do I have to configure so that Postfix is able to send encrypted messages via Lets Encrypt and to check the certificate on the recipient side?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved. The issue was **missing** CA-Certificates on my system. So Postfix was not able to verify the Issuer of the Client.

**Solved by installing**

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates -y
```

**Then pointing Postfix to the new installed CA-Certificates:**

```
sudo postconf -e 'smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
sudo postfix reload
```

**Result:**

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
postfix/smtp[11023]: Trusted TLS connection established to ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem in Postfix for RHEL 8.7

I was seeing this error on gmail.com, hotmail.com, outlook.com connections as being untrusted TLS.

First I made sure the ca-certificate was installed
I typed:   sudo yum install ca-certificates
Once it says it was already installed
I edited the main.cf
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
searched for the smtp_TLS_CA line
commented out my old line with a # and made a note in case I need to reverse it
then added a new line:  smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
saved file
did a restart of the postfix service.   systemctl restart postfix
checked for errors:    systemctl status postfix
then did a test email to a gmail.com user and made sure the log showed it was a trusted TLS connection.
Fixed!